# WMV's Won't Play in Any Browser Except IE

Tags: html, video, wmv

I'm working on a Moodle 2.1 website and I'm running into a problem w/ getting WMVs to play in multiple browsers.

- **IE**: Plays with no problems
- **Firefox**: Displays the windows media player but when I click the play button the video does not start.
- **Chrome**: Displays the windows media player but when I click the
  play button the video does not start.

Here's my HTML for the video:

```
<object classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" 
  standby="Loading Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Media Player components..."
  type="application/x-oleobject">
 <param name="Filename" value="http://mymoodlesite.com/pluginfile.php/1234/mod_forum/attachment/56/mywmvfile.wmv" />
 <param name="src" value="http://mymoodlesite.com/pluginfile.php/1234/mod_forum/attachment/56/mywmvfile.wmv" />
 <param name="url" value="http://mymoodlesite.com/pluginfile.php/1234/mod_forum/attachment/56/mywmvfile.wmv" />
 <param name="ShowControls" value="true" />
 <param name = "controller" value="true" />
 <param name="AutoRewind" value="true" />
 <param name="AutoStart" value="false" />
 <param name="Autosize" value="true" />
 <param name="EnableContextMenu" value="true" />
 <param name="TransparentAtStart" value="false" />
 <param name="AnimationAtStart" value="false" />
 <param name="ShowGotoBar" value="false" />
 <param name="EnableFullScreenControls" value="true" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object data="http://mymoodlesite.com/pluginfile.php/1234/mod_forum/attachment/56/mywmvfile.wmv" type="video/x-ms-wmv" width="400" height="364">
   <param name="src" value="http://mymoodlesite.com/pluginfile.php/1234/mod_forum/attachment/56/mywmvfile.wmv" />
   <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
   <param name="autostart" value="false" />
   <param name="resize" value="scale" />
  </object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Comment: How is that supposed to be helpful to me?

Comment: it's just meant to say "I feel your pain". I don't have anything I can offer to directly help you, but my experience with video in the browser is that it's painful.

Comment: Oh okay. I think I just took you're comment in the wrong context. It's definitely ruining my day...stupid Microsoft.

Comment: I'd abandon WMV and switch to a more widely supported format.

Comment: I totally agree but it's for a client and they insist on using WMV's

Comment: WMVs simply don't work on the web. If they want to publish video on the web, then they need to switch to something that actually works. No amount of insistence will make WMVs practical.

Comment: @Kyle: Is Silverlight an option for you? That would allow you to play back WMV cross browser

Answer (score -2):

Better use Flash based player (JWPlayer or FlowPlayer), or <video> tag from HTML5 with OGG video format.
You definitely shouldn't use WMV in websites...

Comment: I totally agree but it's for a client and they insist on using WMV's